# i am getting an error on using tf.frompixels recently which i wasnt getting before. below is the code i am using

Tags: tensorflow

```
      function preprocessImage(img) {
          const tensor        = tf.fromPixels(img)
                          .resizeNearestNeighbor([224, 224]);
          const croppedTensor = cropImage(tensor);
          const batchedTensor = croppedTensor.expandDims(0);
    return batchedTensor.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(127)).sub(tf.scalar(1));
    }
```

the error i am getting is that tf.fromPixels is not a function . i wasnt getting this error as of two weeks back but i am suddenly getting this error on running the same code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `tf.fromPixels()` has been removed and its function taken over by `tf.browser.fromPixels()`.

[Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/669)